# change style of button with enum dependency property. How to properly bind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, dependency-properties

i am trying to change the style of my button based on its own dependency property. i cant seem to figure out why this is not working. it has got to do with the enum and how to bind it. im am new to WPF and ive been searching forever. please help!
the relevant code. first my button class:

```
public class AmmoType
{
    public enum ammoType { RFS, RFD, RFC, EMPTY }
}

public class DLSButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AmmoTypeProperty;
    public AmmoType.ammoType ammoTypeEnum
    {
        get
        {
            return (AmmoType.ammoType)GetValue(DLSButton.AmmoTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DLSButton.AmmoTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
    static DLSButton()
    {
        DLSButton.AmmoTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ammoTypeEnum", typeof(AmmoType.ammoType), typeof(DLSButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(AmmoType.ammoType.EMPTY));
    }
}
```

my application Ressources (App.xml):

```
<Application.Resources>        
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DLSButton}" x:Key="DLSAmmo">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" >
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">DLS</TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AmmoType+ammoType}" Value="{x:Static my:AmmoType+ammoType.EMPTY}">

                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" >
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">N/A</TextBlock>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ammoTypeEnum}" Value="RFD">

                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" >
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">RFD</TextBlock>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ammoTypeEnum}" Value="{x:Static local:AmmoType+ammoType.RFS}">

                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" >
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">RFS</TextBlock>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ammoTypeEnum}" Value="{x:Static local:AmmoType+ammoType.RFC}">

                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" >
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap">RFC</TextBlock>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>                
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

my XAML where i insert my button:

```
<local:DLSButton ammoTypeEnum="EMPTY" x:Name="buttonDLS1" Style="{StaticResource DLSAmmo}">                            
                    </local:DLSButton>
```

no errors are shown in error list. but when i build the solution a messagebox tells me that: "the property value is not valid"

and as you can see in the different 'DataTriggers' i have tried different things with binding. still no errors. and still no style changing...

Comment: Your binding path is to the actual property; In your case it *might* be `ammoTypeEnum` but its hard to tell. Could you be more specific about the exception you are getting?

Comment: Why are you initializing your property inside a static method? Why isn't it initialized with the rest of the declaration up top?

Comment: Also, what does box actually say verbatim? Does it give a line number? Is the inner exception "the property value is not valid"?

Comment: There is No error in the errorlist in visual studio. It is just a standard messagebox from Windows That says "the property value is not valid" and then i can press 'ok'

Comment: Also. The property is not declared inside the method. It is up top

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext` in your DLSButton class to itself like so: `DataContext = this;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling, I remembered that I hadn't set the data context when I copy/pasta'd your code. That did the trick after fixing some of the datatrigger bindings and values to the values you already had working. Here's what I changed, and it works on my computer:

App.xaml

```
 // so we can see the bg change, but the text changed without it
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
...
// for each of the datatriggers
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ammoTypeEnum}" 
             Value="{x:Static local:AmmoType+ammoType.XXX}">
```

DLSButton.cs

```
// this should be obvious
public partial class DLSButton : Button
{
    public DLSButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: could you please post the full code? my dependency property cannot be placed in the public DLSButton() class because it is a static property

Comment: never mind. i got it to work thank you very much. the solution was as simple as you descriped. setting 'datacontext = this;' and move the dependency property up top.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I actually used your exact code aside from the edits I posted here. The only major difference was adding in the constructor for the DLSButton. I've run into so many problems that seem to be one thing but end up being that I forgot to add the data context.